# Installing local Python module works in Blender Python executable, but not in Blender console

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to learn Blender to make math animations, and since I expect to use it almost exclusively through the Python api, I am writing a library of utilities as I go: https://github.com/bencbartlett/pyblend I would like to be able to import this library within Blender. I have run the following to install it:

```
git clone https://github.com/bencbartlett/pyblend.git
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.93/python/bin/python3.9 -m pip install -e pyblend
```

If I then run `/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.93/python/bin/python3.9` and `import pyblend`, it imports as expected, but when I open Blender and run `import pyblend` in the console, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Strangely, the dependencies for the module which were not previously present (such as matplotlib) are correctly installed, but the module itself is not.

What am I doing wrong and how can I install a local module so that it is importable within Blender?

Answer (score 0):

If you run this script it will print out all the places Blender (or other instance of Python) looks for scripts:

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

You can add to this path at runtime if you need to, I have a plugin that has a libs/ folder under its installed folder. There is code like this to add the library path in the folder the plugin file is running from:

```
import os
import sys
local_module_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),'libs')
if local_module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(local_module_path)
```